# Chef - Run long running script in background

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I want to run a simple script in the background. It needs to be alive for the duration of the entire life of the machine.

```
script "my_script" do
interpreter "ruby"
cwd "/home/my_home"
user "root"
code << -EOH
  pid = fork
  if pid
     Process.detach(pid)
     system("ruby the_actual_script.rb > logfile")
  end
EOH
```

But this does not seem to run, it appears it has run and exited immediately. There is a 0 size logfile. I have the cwd folder set to 777 permission.

Can't figure out what the issue is. I am guessing chef executes this in a different shell and gets rid of all processes once it exits that shell?

Is there a better way to simply run the script in the background?

Comment: Create a service from your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is called a "service". You can place your script in his own file, for example using the "cookbook_file" chef resource. Then write an init script for it, for example using upstart in Ubuntu systems. Once you have an init script, you can use chef's "service" resource to make sure the service is enabled to always run, and that it is started during the first chef run that creates it. Voila!